# How to go to tabbar item from an external view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Im stuck with a problem me and a friend of mine are building a app in ios. [see video.](https://youtu.be/SHrBF6h8Nso)

**please watch this video:**

https://youtu.be/SHrBF6h8Nso

The problem is when we are done with the workout and we get to the finish workout screen and we click on the profile button it goes to the workoutOverview Screen. But we want it to go to the profileOverview screen.

**We try to achieve this with this line of code :**

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1. // this results in segue to workoutOverview instead of profileOverview, no matter what index we use
```

But finish workoutOverview is not part of tabbar controller or the navigation controller that we have.

**the second problem** 
When pressing the cancel button (cross) we would like to pop to the first viewcontroller (muscleList) but without losing the tabbar!

*see how our storyboard is connected in the picture:*

[image]

**Question:**

How to go back to profile view controller in the tabbar controller?
How to show view controller with tabbar controller when click on the cancel button?

If anyone have a idea it would help us a lot.

Comment: On click of cancel button post notification to exercise value setting view controller to move to navigation rootViewcontroller

Comment: @Vinodh I tried with popToRoot but this didn't work! :(

Answer (score 1):

xCode has a bug with the show segues. Change all "Show" segues to the deprecated "Push" segues and build and compile. Than change all back to "Show" again, build, compile and it works now! All viewcontrollers will be added to the stack.